# Angular migration 14 to 15 / 16: Has angular universal ceased to put <!-- this page was prerendered with angular universal --> for pre-rendered pages?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I recently migrated from version 14 of angular to version 15 (and then to 16) and pre-rendering with angular universal seems to have changed: It still *seems* to work afaict but the familiar `<!-- this page was prerendered with angular universal -->` has gone.

Questions:
Can I no longer rely on the added html-comment to quickly verify, prerendering and ssr is working? i.e. is it gone?
If yes, why and why can I not find anything online?
If no, what might I have broken during migration that killed it?

Comment: Yes that comment was removed in v15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since v15, you have `ng-server-context` in your DOM when the content has been generated by universal.

You would either have :

- `ng-server-context="ssr"` when the content is generated dynamically
- `ng-server-context="ssg"` when the content is being prerendered (static site generation)